# sending only a text email instead of html

Tags: php, email

I have this code at the top of my email php file which sends out emails

```
    $headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
    $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
    $headers .= "From: $from <$from>" . "\r\n";
    $headers .= 'Cc: matt.e@posnation.com' . "\r\n";
    $headers .= 'Bcc: posnation@gmail.com' . "\r\n";
```

I need to change this to just a plain text email ...what do i change. I was thinking the second line text/html to text/text but i wasnt sure

Comment: Don't build your own mime emails. Use PHPMailer (http://phpmailer.worxware.com) or Swiftmailer (http://swiftmailer.org). They're far easier to use and much more reliable... and free.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to change the "text/html" to "text/plain".

Answer (score 1):

You can use text/plain

But if you enter html content the tags and all will be shown on the client though ...

But i'm sure there's an alternate way to support both text and html ...

Are you using the built in mail function or an external mail app like phpMailer?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to change anything.

Technically it should be "text/plain", but if you want, you can just as easily send an "HTML" email with no HTML tags and it will work just fine.